Cumulative distribution function of coherent system
The theorem is from here.
Theorem 3.1. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be the i.i.d. component lifetimes of an $n$-component coherent system with signature $s$, and let $T$ be the system's lifetime. Then
$$
\overline{F}_T(t) \equiv P(T > t) = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{n}{j} (F(t))^j \big(\overline{F}(t)\big)^{n-j}.$$
Proof: We first note that the system fails concurrently with the failure of one of its components, so that $T$ will necessarily take on the values of one of the order statistics $X_{i:n}$ of the sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, that is, $T \in \{X_{1:n}, X_{2:n}, \ldots, X_{n:n}\}$ with probability $1$. Then, utilizing the Law of Total Probability and the i.i.d. assumption on component lifetimes, we may write
\begin{align}
P(T > t) &= \sum_{i=1}^n P(T > t, T = X_{i:n})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n P(T > t \mid T = X_{i:n}) P(T = X_{i:n})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n s_i P(X_{i:n} > t)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n s_i \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{n}{j} (F(t))^j \big(\overline{F}(t)\big)^{n-j}
\end{align}
I want to know how the last equality came?
